# Inject DbContext without explicitly passing as constructor argument in .net6.0 console app

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0

I'm trying to do a c# console app (.net6.0).

Here is my program.cs

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var cns = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db");
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseMySql(cns,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cns) ));
    })
    .Build();

//Want to create new instance of Ghonta, without passing DatabaseContext parameter.
Ghonta g = new Ghonta();
```

Ghonta.cs-

```
public class Ghonta{

    private readonly DatabaseContext db;
 
    //Want to inject DatabaseContext from services
    public Ghonta(DatabaseContext DB){
        db = DB;;
    }

}
```

I can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Register it with your dependency injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register Gontha to your services, and get one from the Host instance after you have built it

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    var cns = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db");
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseMySql(cns,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cns) ));
    services.AddScoped<Ghonta>();
})
.Build();

Ghonta g = host.Services.GetRequiredService<Ghonta>();
```

You should be able to use Gontha as expected